# Scikit-learn's SGDClassifier code question

Tags: svm, python, scikit-learn, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent

I have a question regarding the code of function `SGDClassifier`, from library `scikit-learn`, which implements linear classification using the stochastic gradient descent (SGD) algorithm. It concerns its application for the Support Vector Machine (SVM) model - *i.e.* SVM is parametrized by a *hinge* loss function and a *L2* penalty function. The SVM decision function is:

$$
d(x) = sign\left(f(x)\right) = sign\left(w^Tx\right)
$$

The optimal solution $w^*$ is found by solving the following regularized problem ($[x]_+ \equiv \max[0,x]$):

$$
\min_w \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left[1-y_i\,w^Tx_i\right]_+}+\lambda\|w\|^2\right)
$$

From [[Bottou, 2012]](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/192769/tricks-2012.pdf), page 3, I recall the SGD algorithm's main update equation for the SVM:

$$
w \leftarrow w \ - \ \eta_t \left(\lambda w - y_tx_t\mathbf{1}_{\{y_tw^Tx_t<1\}} \right)
$$

However, I am having trouble finding this same equation in `SGDClassifier`. The code of `SGDClassifier` is based on the function [`_plain_sgd()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/89247fcd7f02bbd92c9da141250ec8b82caf8dd0/sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.pyx#L529) written in Cython: for an optimal learning rate (`2`), a hinge loss $-$ see definition of `dloss` in the code from line 108 on; `dloss` for a hinge loss function (SVM) is in line 160 $-$ and a L2 penalty (`2`), and ignoring class and sample weights, I have the impression the value for the `update` of $w$ is computed in line 639 and is equal to `-eta * dloss`:

$$
w \leftarrow w \ - \ \eta_ty_t\mathbf{1}_{\{y_tw^Tx_t<1\}}
$$

There is a last computation in line 656:

`w.add(x_data_ptr, x_ind_ptr, xnnz, update)`

But I do not understand what this does.

Is there anything I have missed on [_plain_sgd code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/89247fcd7f02bbd92c9da141250ec8b82caf8dd0/sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.pyx#L529)? Has anybody a clue on where these differences come from? Especially given that `scikit-learn` [claims](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html) that they follow Bottou's approach:

> The implementation of SGD is influenced by the Stochastic Gradient SVM of Léon Bottou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, with $L_2$ regularization, the update is:

\begin{equation}
w \leftarrow w - \eta_t\lambda w - \eta_t y_t x_t 1_{\{...\}}
\end{equation}

The first two terms corresponds to a simple scaling. It is updated with the line:

`w.scale(max(0, 1.0 - ((1.0 - l1_ratio) * eta * alpha)))`

where the weight `w` are not really updated: to be fast, only a scaling coefficients is updated.

The last term of the update is done with the line:

`w.add(x_data_ptr, x_ind_ptr, xnnz, update)`

The key element is that if the update is sparse, we don't want to update all the weights. The second step only apply the non-zero updates, but the first step would affects all the weights. To avoid that, only a scaling coefficient is updated.

You might want to check [the code of the weight vector](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765acfa4c5d1ec05fc4b406968ad233c75162/sklearn/utils/weight_vector.pyx#L27).

Answer (score 1):

While i can't give you a complete analysis, i'm pretty sure, that these differences are due to the fact, that the implementation is targeting **sparsity** in the data.

Have a look at the **Bottou paper** you linked, especially **part 5.1**! There is a special treatment mentioned for sparse input and the update rule is splitted into several lines.

Further evidence:

- the code-line `w.add(x_data_ptr, x_ind_ptr, xnnz, update)` you refer to: x**nnz** means most of the time **nonzeros** (as in nonzeros of sparse-matrix) like for example [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nnz.html)
- sklearns SGDClassifier is sparse-matrix ready (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.fit))
- personal experience tells me that sparsity-information is used!